# Define OpenXml Styles in pre-existing spreadsheet

Tags: .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using the OpenXml SDK to generate a spreadsheet. I currently use about 5 different cell formats which I define in a style sheet. This works fine, assuming that I am creating a completely new document.

The style sheet looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:styleSheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <x:fonts>
        <x:font>
            <x:sz val="11" />
        </x:font>
        <x:font>
            <x:sz val="18" />
        </x:font>
        <x:font>
            <x:i />
            <x:sz val="11" />
        </x:font>
    </x:fonts>
    <x:fills>
        <x:fill>
            <x:patternFill patternType="none" />
        </x:fill>
        <x:fill>
            <x:patternFill patternType="gray125" />
        </x:fill>
        <x:fill>
            <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
                <x:fgColor rgb="C0C0C0" />
            </x:patternFill>
        </x:fill>
        <x:fill>
            <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
                <x:fgColor rgb="DCDCDC" />
            </x:patternFill>
        </x:fill>
    </x:fills>
    <x:borders>
        <x:border />
        <x:border>
            <x:left style="thin" />
            <x:right style="thin" />
            <x:top />
            <x:bottom />
            <x:diagonal />
        </x:border>
    </x:borders>
    <x:cellXfs>
        <x:xf />
        <x:xf fontId="1" fillId="2" borderId="1">
            <x:alignment horizontal="left" vertical="top" wrapText="1" />
        </x:xf>
        <x:xf fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="1">
            <x:alignment horizontal="left" vertical="top" wrapText="1" />
        </x:xf>
        <x:xf>
            <x:alignment horizontal="left" vertical="top" wrapText="1" />
        </x:xf>
        <x:xf fontId="2" fillId="0" borderId="1">
            <x:alignment horizontal="left" vertical="top" wrapText="1" />
        </x:xf>
        <x:xf fontId="1" fillId="3" borderId="1">
            <x:alignment horizontal="left" vertical="top" wrapText="1" />
        </x:xf>
    </x:cellXfs>
</x:styleSheet>
```

I would like to support a second scenario, in which my program adds a new worksheet into a pre-existing spreadsheet.

This might be:

- a spreadsheet created by my program
- a spreadsheet created by my program, but modified in Excel
- a spreadsheet created by Excel

What would be a best strategy for creating styles in an existing spreadsheet?

Ideally, I would want to detect whether the required styles are already present and if so reuse them. Detecting a style based solely on its definition would be messy code. It would be much more practical if I could assign a unique name to xf elements which I define.

I know that I can define named styles in the cellStyles node, which refer to items in the cellStyleXfs collection, something like:

```
<x:cellStyleXfs>
    <x:xf />
    <x:xf fontId="1" fillId="2" borderId="1">
        <x:alignment horizontal="left" vertical="top" wrapText="1" />
    </x:xf>
    <x:xf fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="1">
        <x:alignment horizontal="left" vertical="top" wrapText="1" />
    </x:xf>
    <x:xf>
        <x:alignment horizontal="left" vertical="top" wrapText="1" />
    </x:xf>
    <x:xf fontId="2" fillId="0" borderId="1">
        <x:alignment horizontal="left" vertical="top" wrapText="1" />
    </x:xf>
    <x:xf fontId="1" fillId="3" borderId="1">
        <x:alignment horizontal="left" vertical="top" wrapText="1" />
    </x:xf>
</x:cellStyleXfs>

<x:cellStyles>
    <x:cellStyle name="Standard"              xfId="0" />
    <x:cellStyle name="ML_Header"             xfId="1" />
    <x:cellStyle name="ML_LanguageText"       xfId="2" />
    <x:cellStyle name="ML_DefaultLeftAligned" xfId="3" />
    <x:cellStyle name="ML_CommentText"        xfId="4" />
    <x:cellStyle name="ML_SubHeader"          xfId="5" />
</x:cellStyles>
```

However, I can't figure out the relationship between items in the cellStyleXfs collection and the callXfs collection.

In addition, Excel behaves like it owns the cellStyles and cellStyleXfs nodes. If I edit the spreadsheet in excel, the deinitions are changed and some of them are removed.

At present, this does not look like a practical solution.

Is there any way that I can assign a name to an xf node in the cellXfs element? That would make life easier.

An alternative approach would be to define new styles (and fonts and fills and borders) every time I generate a worksheet. Done repeatedly, that would make the file larger every time.

What would be the best strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a strategy which is certainly not perfect, but which is good enough for my purpose.

I decided

- to characterize the styles which I use with a fixed set of properties
- to define a function which looks for a style matching these properties
- if it doesn't find one, then create a new style

As a minimum requirement, I wanted the function to at least find the styles which it had generated itself.

If my application exports to the same excel file 100 times, I don't want to generate the identical styles 100 times, making the excel file a little bigger every time.

The set of properties which I specify is incomplete. For example, I do not specify the font family. If there was a style which matched all of my properties, but used a different font, I would still use this style. That is OK for me, but in another application it might be unacceptable.

For historic reasons, my code is in VB, but it could easily be ported to C#.

This is a slightly reduced version of my code. There are 19 different styles, which are initialised by the function CreateStyleSheet(). If the style sheet does not exist at all, then it creates it, before checking for the individual styles.

The main function which searches for or creates a style is FindCellFormat. Its 15 parameters define the set or properties, which it checks for.

For 8 of the styles there is a helper function, FindCellFormatForStatus, but this is not particularly relevant.

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet

Friend Class clsOpenXmlUtil

  'CellFormat IDs
  Public Property CellFormat_ColumnHeader                  As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_LanguageText                  As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_DefaultLeftAligned            As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_CommentText                   As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_ColumnSubHeader               As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_ColumnHeaderSmall             As Integer

  Public Property CellFormat_Location_UI                   As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_Location_Code                 As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_Location_Resource             As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_MultipleUsageTrue             As Integer

  Public Property CellFormat_ComponentHeader               As Integer

  Public Property CellFormat_Status_Unknown                As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_Status_OriginalText           As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_Status_Edited                 As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_Status_GlobalDatabase         As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_Status_ExcelImport            As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_Status_OnlineTranslation      As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_Status_ImportedLocalization   As Integer
  Public Property CellFormat_Status_OutOfDate              As Integer

  Public Sub CreateStyleSheet ( ExlBookPart As WorkbookPart )

    If ExlBookPart.GetPartsCountOfType(Of WorkbookStylesPart) = 0 Then

      Dim ss                    = New Stylesheet()
      Dim fontCollection        = New Fonts()
      Dim fillCollection        = New Fills()
      Dim borderCollection      = New Borders()
      Dim formatCollection      = New CellFormats()

      'This block only defines the default styles.
      'The styles which we actually use are defined in a second step.

      fontCollection.Append   ( New Font        With { .FontSize       = New FontSize    With { .Val         = 11 } } )

      fillCollection.Append   ( New Fill        With { .PatternFill    = New PatternFill With { .PatternType = PatternValues.None } } )
      fillCollection.Append   ( New Fill        With { .PatternFill    = New PatternFill With { .PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125 } } )

      borderCollection.Append ( New Border() )

      formatCollection.Append ( New CellFormat() )

      ss.Append ( fontCollection )
      ss.Append ( fillCollection )
      ss.Append ( borderCollection )
      ss.Append ( formatCollection )

      Dim ExlStyleSheetPart = ExlBookPart.AddNewPart(Of WorkbookStylesPart)
      ExlStyleSheetPart.Stylesheet = ss

    End If

    Dim ExlStyleSheet As Stylesheet = ExlBookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet

    'Check for cell formats with specific attributes. Create the cell formats if necessary.
    CellFormat_ColumnHeader       = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 18, False, False, "C0C0C0", "", BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, False )
    CellFormat_LanguageText       = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 11, False, False, "",       "", BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, True )
    CellFormat_DefaultLeftAligned = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 11, False, False, "",       "", BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, False )
    CellFormat_CommentText        = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 11, True,  False, "",       "", BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, True )
    CellFormat_ColumnSubHeader    = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 18, False, False, "DCDCDC", "", BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, False )
    CellFormat_ColumnHeaderSmall  = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 11, False, False, "C0C0C0", "", BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, False )

    CellFormat_Location_UI        = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 11, False, False, "CCFFCC", "", BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, False )
    CellFormat_Location_Code      = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 11, False, False, "FFFF99", "", BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, False )
    CellFormat_Location_Resource  = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 11, False, False, "CC99FF", "", BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, False )
    CellFormat_MultipleUsageTrue  = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 11, False, False, "CCFFFF", "", BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, False )

    CellFormat_ComponentHeader    = FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet, 18, False, False, "FFFF99", "", BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.None, BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.Thin, BorderStyleValues.None, HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, True, False )

    CellFormat_Status_Unknown              = FindCellFormatForStatus ( ExlStyleSheet, GeneralSettings.ExcelBackground_Unknown,              GeneralSettings.ExcelForeground_Unknown              )
    CellFormat_Status_OriginalText         = FindCellFormatForStatus ( ExlStyleSheet, GeneralSettings.ExcelBackground_OriginalText,         GeneralSettings.ExcelForeground_OriginalText         )
    CellFormat_Status_Edited               = FindCellFormatForStatus ( ExlStyleSheet, GeneralSettings.ExcelBackground_Edited,               GeneralSettings.ExcelForeground_Edited               )
    CellFormat_Status_GlobalDatabase       = FindCellFormatForStatus ( ExlStyleSheet, GeneralSettings.ExcelBackground_GlobalDatabase,       GeneralSettings.ExcelForeground_GlobalDatabase       )
    CellFormat_Status_ExcelImport          = FindCellFormatForStatus ( ExlStyleSheet, GeneralSettings.ExcelBackground_ExcelImport,          GeneralSettings.ExcelForeground_ExcelImport          )
    CellFormat_Status_OnlineTranslation    = FindCellFormatForStatus ( ExlStyleSheet, GeneralSettings.ExcelBackground_OnlineTranslation,    GeneralSettings.ExcelForeground_OnlineTranslation    )
    CellFormat_Status_ImportedLocalization = FindCellFormatForStatus ( ExlStyleSheet, GeneralSettings.ExcelBackground_ImportedLocalization, GeneralSettings.ExcelForeground_ImportedLocalization )
    CellFormat_Status_OutOfDate            = FindCellFormatForStatus ( ExlStyleSheet, GeneralSettings.ExcelBackground_OutOfDate,            GeneralSettings.ExcelForeground_OutOfDate            )

    'So far as I can tell, this is not necessary.
    'ExlStyleSheet.Save()

  End Sub

  Public Function FindCellFormatForStatus ( ExlStyleSheet        As Stylesheet,
                                            FillColour           As System.Drawing.Color,
                                            FontColour           As System.Drawing.Color ) As Integer

    Dim FillColourString = $"{FillColour.R:X2}{FillColour.G:X2}{FillColour.B:X2}"
    Dim FontColourString = $"{FontColour.R:X2}{FontColour.G:X2}{FontColour.B:X2}"

    Return FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet,
                            11,
                            False,
                            False,
                            FillColourString,
                            FontColourString,
                            BorderStyleValues.Thin,
                            BorderStyleValues.Thin,
                            BorderStyleValues.None,
                            BorderStyleValues.None,
                            BorderStyleValues.None,
                            HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left,
                            VerticalAlignmentValues.Top,
                            True,
                            True)

  End Function

  Public Function FindCellFormat ( ExlStyleSheet        As Stylesheet,
                                   FontSize             As Integer,
                                   FontItalic           As Boolean,
                                   FontBold             As Boolean,
                                   FillColour           As String,
                                   FontColour           As String,
                                   LeftBorderStyle      As BorderStyleValues,
                                   RightBorderStyle     As BorderStyleValues,
                                   TopBorderStyle       As BorderStyleValues,
                                   BottomBorderStyle    As BorderStyleValues,
                                   DiagonalBorderStyle  As BorderStyleValues,
                                   HorizontalAlignment  As HorizontalAlignmentValues,
                                   VerticalAlignment    As VerticalAlignmentValues,
                                   WrapText             As Boolean,
                                   Unlocked             As Boolean ) As Integer

    Dim formatCollection  As CellFormats = ExlStyleSheet.GetFirstChild(Of CellFormats)
    Dim fontCollection    As Fonts       = ExlStyleSheet.GetFirstChild(Of Fonts)
    Dim fillCollection    As Fills       = ExlStyleSheet.GetFirstChild(Of Fills)
    Dim borderCollection  As Borders     = ExlStyleSheet.GetFirstChild(Of Borders)

    Dim FormatId          As Integer = -1

    If      formatCollection IsNot Nothing _
    AndAlso fontCollection   IsNot Nothing _
    AndAlso fillCollection   IsNot Nothing _
    AndAlso borderCollection IsNot Nothing _
    Then

      Dim Count As Integer = formatCollection.Elements.Count
      For i As Integer = 0 To Count-1

        Try

          Dim format      As CellFormat = formatCollection.ElementAt(i)

          'I have decided to skip cell formats without related Font, Fill or Border objects.
          If format.FontId   Is Nothing Then Continue For
          If format.FillId   Is Nothing Then Continue For
          If format.BorderId Is Nothing Then Continue For

          'These should now succeed.
          Dim Font   As Font   = fontCollection.ElementAt(format.FontId.Value)
          Dim Fill   As Fill   = fillCollection.ElementAt(format.FillId.Value)
          Dim Border As Border = borderCollection.ElementAt(format.BorderId.Value)

          'Read some values from the format, where we must check for null.

          'As far as I can tell, the italic is usually indicated by the presence of an Italic object.
          'Italic.Value is usually null. If Italic.Value is not null, then I guess we have to consider its value.
          'The same applies to Bold.
          Dim IsItalic              = Font.Italic IsNot Nothing
          Dim IsBold                = Font.Bold   IsNot Nothing
          Dim IsFontSize            = If ( Font?.FontSize.Val.Value, -1 )

          If IsItalic AndAlso Font.Italic.Val IsNot Nothing Then
            IsItalic = Font.Italic.Val.Value
          End If

          If IsBold AndAlso Font.Bold.Val IsNot Nothing Then
            IsBold = Font.Bold.Val.Value
          End If

          Dim IsLeftBorderStyle     = if ( Border.LeftBorder?.Style     Is Nothing, BorderStyleValues.None, Border.LeftBorder.Style.Value     )
          Dim IsRightBorderStyle    = if ( Border.RightBorder?.Style    Is Nothing, BorderStyleValues.None, Border.RightBorder.Style.Value    )
          Dim IsTopBorderStyle      = if ( Border.TopBorder?.Style      Is Nothing, BorderStyleValues.None, Border.TopBorder.Style.Value      )
          Dim IsBottomBorderStyle   = if ( Border.BottomBorder?.Style   Is Nothing, BorderStyleValues.None, Border.BottomBorder.Style.Value   )
          Dim IsDiagonalBorderStyle = if ( Border.DiagonalBorder?.Style Is Nothing, BorderStyleValues.None, Border.DiagonalBorder.Style.Value )

          Dim IsFillColour = ""
          If Fill.PatternFill.PatternType.Value = PatternValues.Solid Then
            'I believe that I have seen both 8 and 6 character values.
            'Tentatively only compare 6 characters
            IsFillColour = If ( Fill.PatternFill?.ForegroundColor?.Rgb?.Value, "" )
            If IsFillColour.Length = 8 Then
              IsFillColour = IsFillColour.Substring(2)
            End If
          End If

          Dim IsFontColour = If ( Font.Color?.Rgb?.Value, "" )
          If IsFontColour.Length = 8 Then
            IsFontColour = IsFontColour.Substring(2)
          End If

          'Unlocked is only meaningful if protection is applies to the worksheet.
          'In this case, all cells are locked unless they are specifically unlocked.
          'As far as I can tell this requires the attribute applyProtection="1" and the child node <protection locked="0">.
          'See also the YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=20&v=KN2Q0vWMd8k
          Dim IsUnlocked = if ( format.ApplyProtection?.Value, False ) AndAlso Not If ( format.Protection?.Locked?.Value, True )

          'Always check for null
          Dim IsHorizontalAlignment  = If ( format.Alignment?.Horizontal?.Value, HorizontalAlignmentValues.General )
          Dim IsVerticalAlignment    = If ( format.Alignment?.Vertical?.Value,   VerticalAlignmentValues.Bottom )
          Dim IsWrapText             = If ( format.Alignment?.WrapText?.Value,   False )

          'Finally start comparing stuff
          If Font.FontSize.Val.Value           <> FontSize            Then Continue For

          If IsItalic                          <> FontItalic          Then Continue For
          If IsBold                            <> FontBold            Then Continue For

          If IsFillColour                      <> FillColour          Then Continue For
          If IsFontColour                      <> FontColour          Then Continue For

          If IsLeftBorderStyle                 <> LeftBorderStyle     Then Continue For
          If IsRightBorderStyle                <> RightBorderStyle    Then Continue For
          If IsTopBorderStyle                  <> TopBorderStyle      Then Continue For
          If IsBottomBorderStyle               <> BottomBorderStyle   Then Continue For
          If IsDiagonalBorderStyle             <> DiagonalBorderStyle Then Continue For

          If IsHorizontalAlignment             <> HorizontalAlignment Then Continue For
          If IsVerticalAlignment               <> VerticalAlignment   Then Continue For
          If IsWrapText                        <> WrapText            Then Continue For

          If IsUnlocked                        <> Unlocked            Then Continue For

          'If we get this far, we will consider it to be a match.
          FormatId = i
          Exit For

        Catch ex As Exception
          'We'll take that as a no shall we?
          Continue For
        End Try

      Next

      If FormatId = -1 Then

        'We did not find the format, so create a new one.
        'The new IDs will be the collection size BEFORE adding a new element.
        Dim FontId   = fontCollection.Elements.Count
        Dim FillId   = fillCollection.Elements.Count
        Dim BorderId = borderCollection.Elements.Count
        FormatId     = formatCollection.Elements.Count

        Dim TextColour  As Color = Nothing
        If FontColour.HasContent() Then
          TextColour = New Color With { .Rgb = New HexBinaryValue ( FontColour ) }
        End If

        fontCollection.Append   ( New Font   With { .FontSize       = New FontSize       With { .Val = FontSize   },
                                                    .Italic         = New Italic         With { .Val = FontItalic },
                                                    .Bold           = New Bold           With { .Val = FontBold   },
                                                    .Color          = TextColour } )

        borderCollection.Append ( New Border With { .LeftBorder     = New LeftBorder     With { .Style = LeftBorderStyle     },
                                                    .RightBorder    = New RightBorder    With { .Style = RightBorderStyle    },
                                                    .TopBorder      = New TopBorder      With { .Style = TopBorderStyle      },
                                                    .BottomBorder   = New BottomBorder   With { .Style = BottomBorderStyle   },
                                                    .DiagonalBorder = New DiagonalBorder With { .Style = DiagonalBorderStyle } } )

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FillColour) Then
          'Use default fill
          FillId = 0
        Else
          Dim fgColour = New ForegroundColor With { .Rgb = New HexBinaryValue ( FillColour ) }
          fillCollection.Append ( New Fill With { .PatternFill = New PatternFill ( fgColour ) With { .PatternType = PatternValues.Solid } } )
        End If

        Dim align  = New Alignment With { .Horizontal = HorizontalAlignment, .Vertical = VerticalAlignment, .WrapText = WrapText }
        Dim format = New CellFormat ( align ) With { .FontId=FontId, .FillId=FillId, .BorderId=BorderId }
        formatCollection.Append ( format )

        If Unlocked Then
          format.ApplyProtection = True
          format.Protection = New Protection With { .Locked = False }
        End If

      End If

    End If

    Return FormatId

  End Function

End Class
```